# sshfs mount causing system to be very slow when remote is down

Tags: fstab, sshfs

What is it about using `sshfs` to mount a remote directory that would cause the following behavior and how do I avoid it?

I have multiple Linux systems and have used `sshfs` to mount a connection from one system to another -- specifically, I mounted a directory on my media server to my desktop as follows:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server openssh-client sshfs
mkdir ~/mnt
mkdir ~/mnt/media-server
mkdir ~/mnt/media-server/Music
sshfs media@media:/home/media/Music ~/mnt/media-server/Music
```

This worked great.  So, using info I found in this article [Systemd automounting sshfs shares](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146674) and others, I added a line in `/etc/fstab` so that it would establish the connection with each reboot.

```
media@media:/home/media/Music  /home/<user>/mnt/media-server/Music  fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/rod/.ssh/id_rsa,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

It still required me to mount it after a boot but this successfully established the connection.

But I encountered something odd: Yesterday, I had both systems shut down.  The media server was still down when I booted my desktop which came up fine but after login, the GUI wouldn't appear. I could access and login `tty2` and others, but `tty7` was -- well, busy, and my drive light was solid.  Thinking it was an anomaly, I did a couple resets with no improvement.

Further investigation showed that any access on the desktop -- opening any app, pretty much anything that involved disk access (isn't that everything?), would be incredibly slow.  The behavior was like it was hitting a time-out; the delay in opening an app or whatever was consistently the same at what seemed like 45 seconds.

I confirmed that the connection to the media server was the issue.  When I brought up the media server, all worked fine again on the desktop -- no delays.  Also, commenting that line in `/etc/fstab` and booting my desktop with the media server still down was also fine.

**UPDATE**
Per the recommendation from Cpt.Whale, I changed the mount point from `/media/<user>` to creating one under `/home/<user>/mnt`.  No improvement in behavior.  In fact, now I see two "Music" mounts and doing `cat /etc/mtab | grep media-server` shows two entries:

```
systemd-1 /home/<user>/mnt/media-server/Music autofs rw,relatime,fd=53,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=23774 0 0
media@media:/home/media/Music /home/<user>/mnt/media-server/Music fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions 0 0
```

So, I commented that line in `/etc/fstab` and just added the manual command at the end of `.bashrc`:

```
sshfs media@media:/home/media/Music ~/mnt/media-server/Music
```

That seemed to work okay -- but only after I open a terminal window :-(.  With a terminal open, nemo will show the mount.  If a terminal isn't open, the mount is not present.  This method does avoid the delay issue I encountered trying to do this through `/etc/fstab`.

There must be a "best practice" way to implement auto-mounting Linux shares.  Previously, I was using samba when the media server was a Windows box and never encountered this issue.

**UPDATE**
After working with this and doing additional research, it seems `sshfs` really isn't intended for regular share access but more occasional file access.  So, going to go over to NFS.

Comment: "removing that `sshfs` connection" – How did you remove it? AFAIK `sshfs` shall not survive a reboot; so unless the mount in question is automated somehow to happen anew at boot, the server being offline should not be an issue.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I've updated the original post to include info on how I was auto-creating the connection at boot.

Comment: using sshfs through `/etc/fstab` can cause freezing as file manager will wait for sshfs to be mounted. You can try adding `x-systemd.device-timeout=10` to your fstab line for a shorter timeout limit, but you may be better off using something like `autofs`. There is probably something on your desktop trying to list files in your home folder, causing your system to try remounting the sshfs and freeze up. You could try just changing the mount location to something like `/mnt/Music` that's less likely to be accessed when the media server isn't up

Comment: @Cpt. Whale: I tried switching to /mnt/media-server/Music but, of course, that is only accessible via sudo and so requires sudo to access anything on that mount.  Is it normal to just chown on things under /mnt to give access to users?  It feels -- well, like it shouldn't be?

Comment: I updated the original to show I'm not longer relying upon /media/<user> and instead created a /mnt directory in my home directory.  Still same issue.